# Difference between "такое" and "так"?

Tags: грамматика

What's the difference between Она часто **такое** говорит and Она часто **так** говорит?

Comment: _Такое_ — ‘such [stuff]’, _так_ – ‘so, thus, this way’.

Answer (score 1):

*Такое* – this word means if you point to an object.
*Так* – this word means exactly how she speaks, for example, “How does she speak?  Beautifully, clearly, etc.”

Answer (score 0):

- "Она часто такое говорит?" - "Does she often say such things?"
- "Она часто так говорит?" - "Does she often say this?"

As @AnnyManny1 stated in the answer "так говорит" may refer to the manner of speech. However, it may also refer to the meaning. In this case, "такое" makes emphasis on the **meaning** while "так" makes emphasis on **exact words**.

One aspect is that it may be disrespectful to use "такое" when referring to someone's speech, because it implies that this speech was dubious. On the other hand, "так" is neutral and does not add any connotations to a citation.